# sum the count of duplicate in a nested list of tuples

Tags: python, nested, tuples

I have a list of tuples that looks like this :

```
[(('review', 'shop', 'draw'), 35),
 (('shop', 'drawing', 'review'), 32),
 (('field', 'review', 'report'), 24),
 (('review', 'shop', 'drawing'), 20),
 (('shop', 'drawing', 'return'), 20),
 (('shop', 'draw', 'review'), 18),
 (('site', 'review', 'report'), 17),
 (('respond', 'rfi', 'regard'), 15),
 (('review', 'fire', 'alarm'), 11),
 (('review', 'lighting', 'shop'), 10)]
```

and I would like to merge those elements that are similar after stemming them alongside with their counts:

```
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer

for elm in trigram_counts:
    ngrams = list(elm[0])
    stemmed_ngrams = []
    for gram in ngrams:
        stemmed_ngrams.append(porter.stem(gram))
        
    print(stemmed_ngrams, elm[1])
```

this gives something like this :

```
['review', 'shop', 'draw'] 35
['shop', 'draw', 'review'] 32
['field', 'review', 'report'] 24
['review', 'shop', 'draw'] 20
['shop', 'draw', 'return'] 20
['shop', 'draw', 'review'] 18
['site', 'review', 'report'] 17
['respond', 'rfi', 'regard'] 15
['review', 'fire', 'alarm'] 11
['review', 'light', 'shop'] 10
```

My goal is to merge for example `['review', 'shop', 'draw']` and `['shop', 'draw', 'review']` with their corresponding sum which is 67

I think I'm complicating it with my solution by over looping through all the elements.

Comment: Is `trigram_counts` the variable that holds your list of tuples?

Comment: What is the criterion for similar? That the tuple contains the same (three) strings, and order doesn't matter? What if a tuple is `('review', 'shop', 'draw', 'fire')` and another tuple is `('review', 'shop', 'draw')`; are these similar?

Comment: I would use a dictionary with `set(inner_tuple)` as its key.

Comment: Instead of adding to a `list`, add to a `set`. Then convert the set to a `tuple`,  use the `tuple` as the key to a `dict` whose values are a running total of the sum you want for that set

Comment: @PM77-1 dict keys must be immutable and hashable, so you can't use a set.

Comment: @00 actually there is no such case when the length of lists are different, and yes order of elements inside doesn't matter, as long as they're the same

Comment: @PranavHosangadi in this case :tuple -> ordered list -> tuple.

Comment: You can sort a tuple to compare them for equality.

Comment: Thanks for your feedbacks I'm trying to implement it based on that

Comment: @PM 77-1 good direction with the `set`, but to make it hashable we need to use `frozenset` in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to combine counts from similar stemmed trigrams you can use a dictionary with [frozensets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) as keys: the keys will be the stemmed trigrams and the values will be the total count.

You have to use frozensets instead sets as keys since the keys of dict must be hashable (which is not the case for the sets).

You will have something like this:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer

stemmed_trigram_counts = defaultdict(int) # use defaultdict to avoid to have to check if the key exist
porter = PorterStemmer()

for trigram, count in trigram_counts:
   stemmed_trigram = frozenset(porter.stem(word) for word in trigram)
   stemmed_trigram_counts[stemmed_trigram] += count

print(stemmed_trigram_counts)
```

This will give you the following output:

```
{
   frozenset({'draw', 'review', 'shop'}): 105,
   frozenset({'field', 'report', 'review'}): 24,
   frozenset({'draw', 'return', 'shop'}): 20,
   frozenset({'report', 'review', 'site'}): 17,
   frozenset({'regard', 'respond', 'rfi'}): 15,
   frozenset({'alarm', 'fire', 'review'}): 11,
   frozenset({'light', 'review', 'shop'}): 10
}
```

Remark: in case the order matter, you should use tuples instead of frozensets